# How to cherry-pick two commits with different ancestors/parents?

Tags: git, gerrit

My commit, `rob`, has a dependency on a commit called `x`. However, `x` has a more recent history than my local branch (it's ancestors/parents are newer), and my local branch is out of date. I want to use `x` in my local branch, and then place my `rob` commit on top of `x` via `git cherry-pick`.

Here is visual representation of the 2 branches (same repository):

My outdated branch:

`old-commit#1`---> `rob`

The branch with the commit I need:

`old-commit#1`--->`new-commit`--->`x`

However, when I cherry-picked `x` and cherry-picked `rob`, and then pushed my changes to `rob` into my local branch, I rewrote the history for `x` and accidentally made a new commit in that remote branch.

How can I prevent doing this in the future? Should I instead `git pull` the `x` commit, and then `git cherry-pick` my `rob` commit on top of that?

Comment: The only way to *rewrite* history with `git push` is with `git push --force`. If you did not do that, you did not rewrite history. If you *did* do that, things get complicated...

Comment: I just used a regular `git push` without the force parameter. By saying that I "rewrote history", I meant that I changed the parent commit of ```x``` on its own local branch

Comment: That's not possible: a commit (as identified by its raw hash ID) is literally un-modifiable. If you take the commit out of the database (so that you can edit the data), do edit the data, and put the edited data back, what you get is not an overwrite of the previous commit, but rather a totally *new* commit, with a new and different hash ID. That's what cherry-picking is for: to make a new commit that resembles an old commit somehow, but is different, with a different hash ID (and usually a different *snapshot*, but the same delta vs its parent).

Comment: The same-diff-vs-new-parent aspect of a cherry-picked commit means that if you use the normal way to *view* a commit—`git show` or `git log -p`—and the same-log-message thing, it will *appear* that you changed the old commit into the new one. This is how `git rebase` works: it does repeated cherry-picks, then abandons all the old (now copied to new and improved) commits in favor of the new-and-improved commits. That's internally a forced history rewrite, which is why after a rebase, you have to use `git push --force`.

Comment: Hello torek, thank you for the information. I did leave out that when I cherry-picked the x commit, I did have to resolve merge conflicts and continue the merge, and then the same scenario when cherry-picking the rob commit. So I think this caused the rewriting of history when I pushed.

Comment: No, having to resolve conflicts is normal: cherry-pick is implemented through Git's merge engine. It remains literally physically impossible to change any existing commit. If you bypass Git and write directly to the database, Git will detect data corruption if the original commit is modified. (This is also how Git detects actual data corruption in the case where, e.g., your disk drive starts delivering corrupt data.)

Comment: I realize this sort of thing is very difficult to reproduce, but if you come up with a [mcve] and post that (add to question, or just close this one and post a new question), someone can show you what's really happening.